# Restricting Numbers in a Matrix

Tags: matrix

I am generating a random N x N matrix, but with a certain restriction. What I'm trying to do is that when there's a "1" in a position, all neighboring positions must turn to "0" (so if [i,j] = 1, then [i+1,j] = [i-1,j] = [i,j-1] = [i, j+1] = 0.)

Currently I am working with something like this:

```
Num = 10
mat = RandomInteger[{0,1},{Num, Num}]

Table[If[themat[[i,j]] == 1, themat[[i+1,j]]==0, themat[[i,j]]]
```

However, I keep getting the error that *"Part specification i is neither a machine-sized integer nor a list of machine-sized integers"*. Could someone please help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: Look at your last line of code. Assuming mat[[row,col]] notation. What happens if it finds a 1 in row 10? When you have figured that out then think about finding a 1 in column 10 or row 1 or column 1 or in each of the four corners? That should be enough of a hint for you to fix the code. Using Table may not be the easiest method to understand in this case.

Comment: @WayneFullen does this only apply to internal elements, i.e. what about corners of array ({1,1},{1,num},{num,1},{num,num}) or boundary?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not well defined because you do not specify adequately what you mean by "random."  You imply that the only entries are **0** and **1**.  Is that what you want?  Do you have a required proportion P of **1**s in the entire matrix where P< 0.5)?  There are numerous trivial "solutions," for instance setting the entries of the entire matrix to **0** except a single entry to **1**.

Please specify your requirements very crisply and completely.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear; what I'm looking for is a uniform distribution for the entire matrix, where the probability of 0 or 1 is equal (the only exception is when there are neighboring 1's, I would want to change those to 0's).

Comment: David,  you address the unclear issues very nicely, but this might be better off as a comment (yet) . @WayneFullen please add all necessary info to the question.

Comment: If your matrix has 50% 1s and 50% 0s and obeys your neighborhood restriction, isn't the only solution equivalent to a checkerboard?

Answer (score 2):

Starting data, biased to zero for a reason that will become apparent:

```
Num = 10
SeedRandom[0]
mat = RandomChoice[{4, 1} -> {0, 1}, {Num, Num}];
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

A matrix with zero in every position that in the original has a one in one of the eight neighboring places:

```
ker = 1 - BoxMatrix[0, 3]

mask = 1 - Unitize@ListCorrelate[ker, mat, {2, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}
> ```
>
> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Multiply (simple multiplication, not matrix multiplication) the two and you get:

```
mask * mat // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

As you can see only three ones survive.

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[filterF];
filterF[mat_, cornerneighbors_: True] := Block[{ker = If[cornerneighbors, 1 - BoxMatrix[0, 3],
   {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}]},
   Developer`PartitionMap[If[FreeQ[ker #, 1], #[[2, 2]], 0] &, mat, {3, 3}, 1, 2, mat]]
```

Using Mr.Wizard's example:

```
SeedRandom[0];
mat = RandomChoice[{4, 1} -> {0, 1}, {10, 10}];
Row[Labeled[MatrixForm@#, #2, Top] & @@@ {{mat, "mat"},
   {filterF@mat, "filterF@mat"}, {filterF[mat, False],"filterF[mat,False]" }}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt to arrive at what I think you meant. However, I doubt that this matrix will have a random distribution since it was processed from a random matrix.

```
Module[{onePositions,aloneOnePositions,onePositionsDeleted,newMatrix,redHighLight},
(* All positions of 1 *)
onePositions=Position[mat,1];

(* All positions of 1 that are not in the neighborhood of any previous positions *)
aloneOnePositions=onePositions//.{a___,b_,c___,d_,e___}/;d==b+{0,1}||d==b+{1,0}:>{a,b,c,e};

(* All positions of 1 that are in the neighborhood of any previous positions *)
onePositionsDeleted=Complement[onePositions,aloneOnePositions];

(* New matrix is formed by replacing all positions of 1 in the neighboorhood of any previous positions to 0 *)
newMatrix=ReplacePart[mat,onePositionsDeleted->0];

(* Display and compare *)
redHighLight[m_]:=ReplacePart[m,aloneOnePositions->Style[1,Red]]//Grid;
redHighLight/@{mat,newMatrix}//Grid[{{"mat","newMatrix"},#},Frame->All]&
]
```

[image]